# Handling Linux without an internet connection?

Tags: linux

The USB WLAN stick I'm trying to use on my linux box is not working properly (tried various distros... none work). Unfortunately some of the install instructions require Wine and cabextract. So I tried to figure out how to install those without an internet connection. Gdebi seems to be the way, but then how do you install that without an internet connection?

After a lot of frustration, I figured I'd go watch a movie. Of course I didn't have the codec and media player offered to look for one on the internet. Doh. Looked around on google, but even installing codecs without an internet connection seems to be non-trivial.

So I'm wondering, are there any resources out there that make it easy to handle linux without an internet connection? Are there any distros that make it easier?

Comment: Just so you know: GDebi isn't the only way to manually install a .deb file. You can just double-click it to open it with the Software Center, or you can run `sudo dpkg -i epic-program_9000.1.78-101.deb` to install it from the Terminal. (Obviously, replace `epic-program_9000*` with the .deb file you downloaded.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are programs to help handle Ubuntu, Debian systems without an internet connection:

- [Keryx Project](http://keryxproject.org/)

  > Keryx is a portable, cross-platform package manager for APT-based (Ubuntu, Debian) systems. It provides a graphical interface for gathering updates, packages, and dependencies for offline computers.
- [APTonCD](http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/)

  > APTonCD is a tool with a graphical interface which allows you to create one or more CDs or DVDs (you choose the type of media) with all of the packages you've downloaded via APT-GET or APTITUDE, creating a removable repository that you can use on other computers.
- [Ubuntu Offline Installers](http://hacktolive.org/wiki/Ubuntu_offline_installers)

  > Script to do an offline install of the ubuntu-restricted-extras package, which contains the additional multimedia codecs, Abobe Flash player, libdvdcss, Java etc.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a similar issue - I was without personal internet for about 60 days, but still had internet through a heavily regulated and locked down Windows laptop at work. If you're using Ubuntu or Debian you can do what I did.

So I would basically go to add the packages I needed in Synaptic on my offline computer, see what the dependencies were, wrote them down, and then manually downloaded all those deb packages from packages.ubuntu.com.

Now, I had to actually boot the Windows computer with a LiveCD just to get the ability to get stuff off the hard drive (via USB and/or burned CD), but in an ordinary situation a USB thumb drive would work just fine. Once you get the deb files on your Ubuntu system you can just double click and GDebi will install them within the framework of your package manager.